# Numbering Elements in a Linked List of structs

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list, element

I am trying to write a function that takes in as an argument a linked list of structs. One of the elements of these structs is a value for storing the position, example struct #3 has 3 for the element. The list that comes in is not in order. I want to go through each element in the linked list and set the value based on the order they are in. How would I do this?

```
nodeT numberStructs(nodeT *temp)
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
    temp->struct.struct_order=i;
    temp=temp->next;
    i++;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This is clearly not going to cut it but it's what I got so far.
Also, to clarify, I will be adding elements, moving elements, deleting elements etc. Instead of adjusting the counts every time do something that changes the line order, I want to call a single function to straighten these out. This allows me to just change the pointers of the linked list structs whenever I want to make a change.

Comment: Could you post some code? What have you tried?

Comment: `int i = 0; Node *node = head; while (node != 0) { node->number = ++i: node = node->next; }`?  But you really do need to show enough of your code to make it easier for people to help you without having to guess what your structures look like.  See how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What's the use of such a field? Are you going to update all of these numbers when you add an element at the front?

Comment: `temp` is defined as a pointer to nodeT and the function nunberStructs is defined as a nodeT yet you are returning a pointer to nodeT. I'd be surprised if the compiler will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct NodeT {
  struct Node *next;
  int struct_order;
  ...
} NodeT;

void fill_idx(NodeT *first) {
  int idx;
  NodeT *node;
  for (node = first, idx = 0;
       node;
       node = node->next, ++idx) {
    node->struct_order = idx;
  }
}
```

Equivalently, with a while loop:

```
void fill_idx(NodeT *first) {
  int idx = 0;
  NodeT *node = first;
  while (node) {
    node->struct_order = idx;
    node = node->next;
    ++idx;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the for loop here? I am coming from java to C and I am not used to 4 arguments. Also why did you call your iterator idx? Just curious

Comment: @itrimara - you wanted to assign order value to member `struct_order`, hence the `idx` interger counter. The for loop is equivalent to your while loop.

Comment: So what struct is the new "head"? Where is the beginning of the linked list?

Comment: I don't see how this code will store the linked list after each iteration of the loop. It looks like it visits each element, sets it and then when node becomes the next, the data is lost. Is this correct?

Comment: @itimara: If this code doesn't do what you need, please explain more clearly what you need. Please also give many more examples (with input, expected output etc.). Without that it's very hard for me to understand what you need, I can only make wild guesses. Do you want to create a new list, or do you want to modify the existing list? Do you want to reorder the elements in the output?

Comment: To clarify, I would like to pass in an unordered list. This list is a linked list of structs. They all contain a value element which is an int representing line position. The element should start from 1 in the first element and ascend to the Nth int for the Nth element. The end result is to set the linked list that was passed in to the new numbered list. For example sortList(theList) will either change theList in memory or return a linked list that can be set to theList by calling theList = sortList(theList). I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the elements of your input linked list are in the wrong (arbitrary) order, and the function should reordered them based on the index in struct_order? (Please add an example input and example output to the question.)